# How disable debug console Libevent?

Tags: c, libevent

Tell me please, How disable debug console Libevent ?

It says here: [http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/Ref1_libsetup.html](http://www.wangafu.net/%7Enickm/libevent-book/Ref1_libsetup.html)

```
#define EVENT_LOG_DEBUG 0
#define EVENT_LOG_MSG   1
#define EVENT_LOG_WARN  2
#define EVENT_LOG_ERR   3

/* Deprecated; see note at the end of this section */
#define _EVENT_LOG_DEBUG EVENT_LOG_DEBUG
#define _EVENT_LOG_MSG   EVENT_LOG_MSG
#define _EVENT_LOG_WARN  EVENT_LOG_WARN
#define _EVENT_LOG_ERR   EVENT_LOG_ERR
```

But It doesn't work a damn thing, debug information is still printed to the console.

Comment: So what exactly doesn't work? What did you do to disable it?

Comment: @StaceyGirl,  #define EVENT_LOG_DEBUG 0. but debug information is still printed to the console.

Comment: But `EVENT_LOG_DEBUG` is already defines as 0. It changes nothing. Any changes to those also only affect code being built, not library that has been built already. The link you mention says libevent allows you to setup logging function - I think you should try doing this first.

Comment: `To override Libevent’s logging behavior, write your own function matching the signature of event_log_cb, and pass it as an argument to event_set_log_callback(). Whenever Libevent wants to log a message, it will pass it to the function you provided. You can have Libevent return to its default behavior by calling event_set_log_callback() again with NULL as an argument.` Which part is unclear to you? Also `void event_enable_debug_logging(ev_uint32_t which);`

Comment: @KamilCuk, but It does not say anything about disabling the debug mode.